# Ajax with external parameter Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am new to angular and what I am willing to do is replace a piece of code I wrote in the past in jquery to angularjs.

The goal is to take a string from a span element, split it in two and pass the two strings as parameters in a GET request.

I am trying to learn best coding pratices and improving myself so any comments of any kind are always welcome.

Working Code in jquery:

```
//Get Song and Artists  

setInterval(function () {
var data = $('#songPlaying').text();
var arr = data.split('-');

var artist = arr[0];
var songTitle = arr[1];

//Request Lyrics

$.get('lyricsRequester.php', { "song_author": artist, "song_name" : songTitle}, 
function(returnedData){
     console.log(returnedData);
    $('#refreshLyrics').html(returnedData);
});
},10000);
```

Code in Angular

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);


app.factory('lyricService', function($http) {
   return {
        getLyrics: function($scope) {
        //$scope.songArr = $scope.currentSong.split('-'); <-- **undefined currentSong**
        //$scope.artist = $scope.songArr[0];
        //$scope.songTitle = $scope.songArr[1];
             return 
             $http.get('/lyricsRequester.php', {
        params: {
            song_author: $scope.artist,
            song_name: $scope.songTitle
        }
     }).then(function(result) {
            return result.data;
                        });
        }
   }
});

app.controller('lyricsController', function($scope, lyricService, $interval) {
   $interval(function(){ 

        lyricService.getLyrics().then(function(lyrics) {
            $scope.lyrics = lyrics; <-- **TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**
            console.log($scope.lyrics);
        }); 

        }, 10000);
});
```

index.html (just a part)

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-controller="lyricsController">{{lyrics}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><h3><span id="currentSong" ng-model="currentSong"></span></h3><div>
```

Comment: This might help with the service scoping - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503202/how-does-one-scope-an-angularjs-factory-service-to-return-unique-data-to-a-speci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful with your `return` statement when used in conjunction with newlines, in these lines:

```
return 
$http.get('/lyricsRequester.php',
```

If you don't, JS will automatically add a semicolon after your `return`, and the function will return `undefined`.

Move the `$http.get` statement to the same line as your return statement.

```
return $http.get('/lyricsRequester.php', ...
```

Refer to the following docs:

[MDN return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

[Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion)

---

As for your second issue, you $scope is not really something you inject into your services (like $http). Scopes are available for use in controllers.
You need to refactor your code a bit to make things work.

eg. Your `getLyrics` function can take a song as a parameter. Then in your controller, you call `lyricsService.getLyrics(someSong)`. Scope access and manipulation are only done in your controller.

```
app.factory('lyricService', function($http) {
   return {
        getLyrics: function(song) {
        var songArr = song.split('-');
        var artist = songArr[0];
        var songTitle = songArr[1];
        return $http.get('/lyricsRequester.php', {
          params: {
              song_author: artist,
              song_name: songTitle
          }
     }).then(function(result) {
            return result.data;
                        });
        }
   }
});
app.controller('lyricsController', function($scope, lyricService) {
    $scope.currentSong = 'Judas Priest - A Touch of Evil';

   $interval(function(){ 
        lyricService.getLyrics($scope.currentSong).then(function(lyrics) {
            $scope.lyrics = lyrics;
            console.log($scope.lyrics);
        }); 

        }, 10000);
});
```

---

You also have some other issues, like using ng-model on your span. ng-model is an angular directive that is used in conjunction with form elements (input, select etc.), not a span as you have. So you might want to change that into an input field.

Comment: thank you! that seems to solve one of the two problems of mine!  I see the undefind currentSong only now.

Comment: You're trying to inject and access $scope in your service. $scope can only be injected into controllers.

Comment: ah that's true, i passed it from the controller and the request is visible through the console now. Many thanks to all of you :)

Comment: I still need it on a span but i managed to do it with jquery text() temporary until I find an other way to pass it. Works great anyways. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

$http does not use .then, it uses .success and .error.  the line that you have where it says then is undefined, should be replaced with a success and error handler instead.  Below is a sample from the docs:

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

See Link:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: thanks but the TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined persists in the controller. If I uncomment $scope.songArr = $scope.currentSong.split('-'); I get undefind currentSong